# Markov Chains terminology

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I am a little confused about how we interpret the mathematical statement $Pr\{X^{(t+1)}=i_{t+1}|X^{(t)}=i_t\}$. If we were to translate this statement in English, would we say "the probability that $X^{(t+1)}=i_{t+1}$ and at the same time $X^{(t)}=i_t$", or "the probability that $X^{(t+1)}=i_{t+1}$ given that $X^{(t)}=i_t$"

Comment: The latter. Another possibility is to say “assuming” instead of “given.”

Answer (score 1):

If we're considering a discrete state space $S$ with $n$ components labeled $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, then we can represent the act of "transitioning" from one state (call it $i$) to another state (call it $j$) by an entry in an $n \times n$ matrix $P$, where $P_{ij} := \mathbb{P}[X^{(t+1)} = j \text{ }| \text{ } X^{(t)} = i]$ and the rows of $P$ sum to 1.

In this way, the $i$th row represents how the process might evolve assuming that we start from state $i$. Since we want the evolution to "make sense", the $i$th row must represent a discrete probability distribution in that the entries are nonnegative and together they sum to 1). So, the transition from assumed state $i$ to any possible state $j \in S$ is specified by $P_{ij}$

When we consider infinite state space models, we can think of the operator (matrix) $P$ generalizing to a kernel $P(x,y)$ which is like an "update rule" in continuous space. See [here](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring12/sta376/lec/mcmctheory.pdf!) for a nice reference.